# Requiring Gulp in composer.json

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, gulp, composer-php

How can I require Gulp in a `composer.json` file? The `composer` (`php>=7.0`) should install `gulp` and `gulp-sass` (and probably `npm`) for a developer who has not installed them. The possible solution should be the code to add in a `composer.json` file. I want to know how developers handle this situation. How do they create a composer-ready development project?

Comment: Why should that be possible? Gulp is not a PHP package, but uses completely different stuff, and Composer is not meant to do this

Comment: PHP developers could use SASS and benefit from Gulp or other packages to developer a front-end. I want to know how developers handle this situation. How do they create a composer-ready development project?

Comment: I think they would install NPM before starting to work on their frontend, just like they have to install PHP before starting in the backend. I've never seen anything else, having worked in multiple projects over the years

Comment: Maybe this approach is the only solid solution, but let's see SO users other solutions in this regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asset Packagist might be the solution : https://asset-packagist.org/site/about

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    }
],
"require": {
    "npm-asset/gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "npm-asset/gulp-sass": "^4.1.0"
}
```

Comment: I've just tested it; there is an error: `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.` It requires some dependencies: `- npm-asset/gulp-sass 4.1.0 requires npm-asset/node-sass `

Comment: I attempt to require the other dependencies, but there is no way to match them! Like: A needs Bv2, C needs Bv1

Comment: I thought it was possible since the packages are available, but, indeed, this closed issue ( https://github.com/hiqdev/asset-packagist/issues/21#issuecomment-264481726 ) seems to say the opposite. I have no other leads ...

Answer (score 1):

NPM has it's own file `packages.json` to hold dependencies. When you install a new project you have to run `npm install` and all packages will be installed on the system in the `node_modules` folder. But first you have to install npm in your own. Every system has it's own package manager to install npm and most people download it from the website to get the latest version.

I think it's not really common to run everything from your composer file. I think it's possible but not really common.

https://nodesource.com/blog/an-absolute-beginners-guide-to-using-npm/

Comment: In this problem, only the `composer` is responsible to handle dependencies and install `npm`, so the possible solution should install `npm` and `gulp`

Comment: You wrote that it's for a developer. A developer should really be able to run 2 commands to install a project ;) in most cases you need npm to run other commands. So whats the problem in this? Otherwise you have to put a Shell Script in you root directory to run all commands.

Comment: :) Thanks, but s/he could install all requirements by running a single command `composer install`. That is why we use `composer`.

Comment: @C2121 that sounds like you need to use a separate task system. Such as Invoke. Set that up to have one command that calls composer and invoke. I'm not certain but composer might have a way to create a php script that is called but this would be "hacky" to call npm.

Comment: @RenéHöhle: Yes. Therefore, I need the best solution for this problem. This would be a common problem for composer users, but I have not found a solid, high-quality solution yet!